# Can i have multiple recyclerviews with same item layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have differents screens that use recyclerview but they have a very similar item layout. The item layout is basically a textview and an image. The image is the same and never changes and the textview style is the same but the text changes because it comes from the api.

I started using the same item layout for each recyclerview because it was very similar but i don't know how to make it work and if it would take too much time

Comment: Please describe your question with code sample 
What did you try so far.

Comment: Sure, why not? You only need separate adapters. You maybe could even abstract that away and use a common adapter by making the item type an interface.

Comment: I didn't think i need to explain more but i will do that

Comment: @Tenfour04 someone told me that i will need to hide the field from the other screen when i go to the other one

Comment: Your adapter can take care of hiding the third view.

Comment: What would take more time to do an adapter with two items or make each recyclerview with different item?

Comment: @Billy80123 I see that you are new here. When you ask questions you need to be as specific as possible. I don't understand your problem. I would always suggest code but if you cant, you need to be extremely specific on what you are trying to achieve. For example, I don't know if you have two recyclerviews side by side, different views within a single recyclerview, just trying to recycle the xml layout. We can't answer if we don't know the question.

Comment: I just wanted to know if this was possible to do and if it's if it would be an optimal solution because i think it can take too much time

Comment: But it's not two recyclerviews side by side. There are differents screens that use exactly the same item layout in the recyclerview. It's one identical textview and one image that doesn't change. The only thing that changes is the textview that comes from the api.

Comment: @Billy80123 I edited my previous post with a little more detail on how to ask the question. I still don't know your problem, it can mean different things. Have a look at it and edit the question. I will see if I have an answer.

Comment: I edited my question now

Comment: @Billy80123 I added an answer.  This way you can use the same layout with the same adapter. Let me know if that is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simplest way to change what to display. You can pass a boolean in the constructor of the adapter from the parent classes.

For example, If it is true, show some data. If it is false you can show some other data.

```
class RecyclerAdapter(var displayUserData: Boolean) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {...}

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = values[position]
        if(displayUserData){
            holder.textView.text = item.name
        }else{
            holder.textView .text = item.otherStuff
        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {...}
}
```

Then set the adapter with true or false

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val adapter = RecyclerAdapter(true)
}
```